# Is it mandate to turn off huge pages in Mysql 5.6

Tags: mysql-5.6, ubuntu

Folks,

Is it required to turn off huge pages in Mysql 5.6 server under /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled  -> To never?

We have a heavy transactional database and calling the data segments quite often for a few particular tables by its index.

How does a memory foot-print work here? Would it help or degrade the performance.

In AnonHugePages:  109242368 kB ( I see entire innodb buffer pool size is occupied under AnonHugepages).

No specific issues found so far due to memory. But need an advise on when to keep it on and when to turn it off.